# "buttonPressed" is not listed in pop-up menu when I followed the "Tap Me!" iOS tutorial by Mike Jaoudi in raywenderlich.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm studying the iOS app dev tutorial in http://www.raywenderlich.com/25561/learn-to-code-ios-apps-3-your-first-app.

At the part of "Connecting the Dots", when I tried to do "With the cursor over the “Tap Me” button, hold down the Control key, then click and drag to anywhere in the green background.", I don't see the expected buttonPressed item, but see below:

[image]

I guess it may be caused by my Xcode is updated to the latest version 6.0.1, and my Macbook update to Yosemite.

Could someone tell me what the correct operation to connect the Button pressed action to the method buttonPressed in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dragging to the green background, drag from your button up to the icon which represents the view controller, at the top of the scene. It's the object that at which the red arrow points in this picture:

[image: Dragging to the View Controller]